# SharePoint 2013 Programming Labs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Since I am programmer I thought it would be better to hear from other programmers about how they learn about SP 2013

SharePoint 2013 is huge and so are the system requirements. Its so difficult if one has to learn SP2013 on his own in such case.

I want to learn SP2013 programming, I am new to it. I have no idea how to start with this. I have thought of few ideas like follows:
1. Virtual machine, however they need even higher configuration than the SP2013 itself.
2. MS Virtual Labs, its great way to learn, however there are no SP2013 labs and even if there are, the labs would end in 2 hours and then one need to start from scratch.
3. I can learn 2007 or 2010, but a lot has changed in 2013. Besides there is no point spending time on something which will be obsolete soon.

I am not sure what other options do I have, I would like to know from the SP2013 programmer here in this community, how you did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is no point spending time on something which will be obsolete soon

I don't think you learn with SP 2010 would be soon obsolete. You can still apply the same methods at most of the customers, event with SP 2013.

Unfortunately, the official MS SP 2010 VHDs are no more available and there are no SP 2013 VHDs as well, however you can create your own VMs using trial versions (for example you can download SP 2010 trial [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16631), or get SP 2013 trial [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sharepoint-server-2013)). [This document](http://files.cnblogs.com/happyhzs2000/CriticalPathTraining_SharePoint2013_VirtualMachineSetup_v1.0.pdf) from Critical Path Training is very useful for SP 2013 setup.

The official HW requirements for SP 2013 are really scary, but I found you can create a VM (including SQL + SP + VS + Office) using about 8 GB of RAM in guest OS for learning purposes.

You can get the [SharePoint 2010 Developer Training Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/SP2010DevTrainingCourse.aspx) or go for SP 2013-related infos [here](http://dev.office.com/).

You can play with the new cloud-related features using trial subscriptions for [O365](https://products.office.com/en-us/try) and [Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an account [here](http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/free-sharepoint-2013) for trial version. Though it does not give you a full fledged access, but it might be of help for individuals who want to gain familiarity with Sharepoint.

Comment: I think the site is currently down!!